# How to create a text file using cmd in c#?

Tags: c#, cmd, command, arguments

I wanted to create a text file with all names of the files in a folder.
So I went like this:

```
Process getNamesProcess = new Process();
getNamesProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"c:\**my folder path**";
getNamesProcess.StartInfo.Arguments = "dir /b >> names.txt";
getNamesProcess.Start();
```

However this doesn't work for me. The process opens me a folder, nothing more. What should I change?

Comment: Note: ">>" will append to an existing file; Probably not what you want. ">" will truncate an existing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what you were hoping to accomplish by placing a folder path in `StartInfo.FileName`, but what you need to put in there is the full path to `cmd.exe`.

Then, in `StartInfo.Arguments` you need to put `"/C dir /b " + my_folder_path + " >> names.txt"`.

For an explanation of what the `/C` does, open up a command prompt and type `help cmd`.

Answer (score 1):

A better way would be:

```
File.WriteAllLines("names.txt", Directory.GetFiles("c:\\path").Select(Path.GetFileName));
```

The `File`, `Directory` and `Path` classes are in the `System.IO` namespace.

Comment: thanks for the answer, this creates me a file with full paths of the files tho, not just names